# How to assign parameter values in a SparqlParameterizedString

Tags: sparql, parameterized, dotnetrdf, blank-nodes

I'm playing around some with Dotnetrdf's sparql engine and I'm trying to create parametered queries with no success yet.

Say I'm working on a graph g with a blank node identified as _:1690 with the code

```
Dim queryString As SparqlParameterizedString = New SparqlParameterizedString()
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("rdfs", UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"))

queryString.CommandText = "SELECT ?label { @context rdfs:label ?label } "
queryString.SetParameter("context", g.GetBlankNode("1690"))

Dim result As VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlResultSet = g.ExecuteQuery(New SparqlQueryParser().ParseFromString(queryString))
```

Whenever I run this, I get all nodes having a rdfs:label property instead of filtering the result on my blank node only.

Please, how to set the parameter's value properly so I get only one item in the result ?

Thanks in advance,
Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank Nodes in a SPARQL query differ from Blank Nodes in a RDF Graph

In a SPARQL Query a blank node is treated as a temporary variable which has limited scope, it does not match a specific blank node so you **cannot** write a SPARQL query to select by blank node identifier.

So your code creating your query is giving a result the same as if you replaced `@context` with a variable e.g. `?s`

If you need to find the value associated with a specific blank node then you need to formulate a query that uniquely selects that blank node based on the triples it participates in.  If you can't do that then you need to re-think your data modelling since if this is the case then you should likely be using URIs instead of blank nodes.

---

As a workaround since you are using dotNetRDF and have the original graph you are querying you can use the `IGraph` API instead e.g.

```
INode label = g.GetTriplesWithSubjectPredicate(g.GetBlankNode("1690"), g.CreateUriNode("rdfs:label")).Select(t => t.Object).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just remember that `label` could always be null if the triple you are looking for doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks Rob, I thought that evaluating the query against the graph from which the node originates would match. As you advise, I will then identify nodes by loading my graph with URIed nodes instead of blank nodes.

Comment: By the way, I have not yet browsed your API in depth. Is there an RDF->Entity part in it or is dotnetrdf fully triple oriented ?

Comment: Rob, one more question :
since I'll mainly need to run the same queries over and over with just a change of context at evaluation time, is it possible to parse and compile the query for caching and defer parameters resolution until really needed ?

Comment: Not really without writing a lot of code yourself, the basic problem is that this kind of pre-compiled plans doesn't work well for SPARQL because the type of term you inject can result in a completely different query plan.  Generally speaking parsing should not be a performance bottleneck, if in your coding you are able to prove otherwise we'd love to know about it

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's just that this pattern is quite common so I wondered ;) Be sure I'll let you know if I encounter problems; )

Comment: Hi again Rob,
actually I found out that a single query takes about .01s to parse (at best and on my computer) is that normal ? Since I would have 30 or so queries per item and 20 item per page, it would theoretically take 6s for the page to load since I would have to create queries for each property by item (some properties may be multivalued so a single joined query may generate duplicate partial result per item) ... Or is there a a better policy to handle this ? I can't see one for now. Thanks for your advice

Comment: If you really have that many queries to make then you probably need to consider how to combine those into a smaller number of queries, this is really another general SPARQL question so I would suggest asking a new question here or at answers.semanticweb.com on the topic.  Remember to include examples of the various different queries you are writing

Comment: Hi Rob, in fact I'm redescovering SPARQL with the 1.1 spec (which seems much more fun to use than 1.0). Finally I think I can prefetch propertypaths for my whole dataset in a single query for each using the VALUES clause.